# Exercise about probability/combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Hello could someone explain to me how to solve a exercise like this one:

"in how many ways can x letters be divided into y pairs"

I'm taking a math course after many years not doing it, so I'm stuck on my first book exercise. Thank you so much!

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What exactly does that mean to divide $x$ letters into $y$ pairs?

Comment: May we assume here that $2y=x$?

Comment: @drhab yes, if you want me to I can come up with a example. The one from the book is very long.

Comment: @JacksonShaw can letters be repeated? Or is every letter distinct?

Comment: An example can only do good.

Comment: No the letters, cannot be repeated.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! In its current state, the question is not very clear. Please add information about the presence or absence of constraints on the letters and their division. Please add this information in the question itself, rather than comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows $x=2y$.

---

If the pairs are ordered then you first pick out $2$ letters, after that from the remaining letters you pick out $2$ letters, et cetera.

That gives $$\binom{2y}2\times\binom{2y-2}2\times\cdots\times\binom42\times\binom22=\frac{(2y)!}{2!2!\cdots2!}=2^{-y}(2y)!$$possibilities.

However the order does not matter, so to repair we must divide by $y!$ and arrive at:$$\frac{(2y)!}{2^yy!}$$ possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all letters are distinct, the trick is to use the product principle. You have $x$ letters. Choose 2 of them to form a pair. There are $_{x}C_2 = \dfrac{x!}{2!(x-2)!}$ ways. Regardless of which two were chosen for the first pair, that leaves $x-2$ letters, and you need to choose another pair. There are $_{(x-2)}C_2 = \dfrac{(x-2)!}{2!(x-4)!}$ ways to choose two letters from $x-2$. By the product principle, the way to choose the first two pairs is:

$$\left(_{x}C_2 \cdot _{(x-2)}C_2 \right) = \dfrac{x!}{2!{(x-2)!}}\cdot \dfrac{{(x-2)!}}{2!(x-4)!} = \dfrac{x!}{(2!)^2(x-4)!}$$

As you keep choosing pairs, you eventually wind up with:

$$\dfrac{x!}{(2!)^y}$$

Edit: I forgot to divide by the number of ways to order the $y$ pairs, because you can choose them in any order, so my method is currently over-counting $y!$ times.

The final answer would be (as drhab showed):

$$\dfrac{x!}{(2!)^yy!} = \dfrac{(2y)!}{(2\cdot 1)^y y!} = \dfrac{(2y)!}{2^y y!}$$